# How to programaticaly update popover?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

How to programaticaly update element-ui popover?
I tried this:

```
 <el-popover
   placement="bottom"
   ref="popover"
   title="Title"
   width="200"
   trigger="click"
   content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
   <el-button slot="reference">Click to activate</el-button>
</el-popover>

this.$refs.popover.update();
```

But it dose not work.
I read in official documentation that it can do by using instance to [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/lifecycle/#manual-update) that use element-ui component.

But I can't get that instance.
Help me resolve problem please))

Comment: What are you trying to update, the content?

Comment: No position like this https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/lifecycle/#manual-update

Comment: Where do you see in the documentation that? I cannot find it from the elemen ui documentation. Only saw that `options` accept popper js options.

Comment: it not exist in element ui documentation, but present in popper.js documentation.And that element ui component should have possibillity comunicate with native code.